# Google analytics for any domain

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain

Is there any way to track analytics for for all domains except a specific one?
If I develop a tool that will be integrated in some websites, I don't know what is the domain to track, but I would track the access from any domain.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The Google Analytics tracking code will work for all domains if you set the Cookie Domain to auto (or "none", but that has side effects  that "auto" has not). You can then filter or segment by hostname to get data for individual domains.

However this is not the same as "cross-domain" (since you tagged your question with that). Cross domain tracking means "tracking multiple domains as one property", so GA sessions will be maintained even when crossing domain boundaries. This is not relevant at all to your use case.

Maybe it would be better if you implemented tracking via the [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/). If you simply add GA tracking code to existing websites you might break tracking that is already there, if you build your own solution on top of the measurement protocol you don't have to worry about that but you can still use the standard GA reporting interface.